# How to validate click of h:outputLink with imagined required="true"?

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, required

I'm trying to put validation in my Link. when the user click on commandButton without click on outputLink user gets an error message. I'm using `required="true"` but it doesn't work.

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLink value="https://www.google.com/" required="true">test</h:outputLink>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit"    action="#{userTest.test()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate a required hidden input with the link and set its value via JS.

Here's a kickoff example which assumes the hidden input is 1st sibling of the link.

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLink 
        value="http://google.com" 
        target="_blank"
        onclick="this.nextSibling.value=true">test</h:outputLink>
    <h:inputHidden 
        required="true" 
        requiredMessage="You need to click that link!" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```